Find the closed form value of the sum $\sum_{i=0}^n e^\frac{i}{n}$.
The problem:
Find the closed form value of the sum $\sum_{i=0}^n e^\frac{i}{n}$.
What I have tried:
I haven't tried anything. I think I am to utilize the formula $\sum_{i=1}^n r^{i-1}=\frac{r^n-1}{r-1}$ if $r \neq 1$ somehow. But what represents $r$ in the problem? No solution is provided for this problem.

Hint: $e^{i/n} = \left(e^{1/n}\right)^{i}$.

Note that
$$\sum_{i=0}^n e^{\frac{i}{n}} \ = \ \sum_{i=0}^n r^i,$$
where $r = e^{\frac{1}{n}}$.
So then, use the formula
$$\sum_{i=0}^n r^i = \frac{r^{n+1}-1}{r-1}$$, $r = e^{\frac{1}{n}}$:
$$\sum_{i=0}^n e^{\frac{i}{n}} = \frac{\big(e^{\frac{1}{n}}\big)^{n+1}-1}{e^{\frac{1}{n}} -1} = \frac{e^{\frac{n+1}{n}}-1}{e^{\frac{1}{n}} -1}.$$

You forgot to remove "Use the formula" at the beginning.
